# Absolute value of sum of additive characters of $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: finite-fields, characters, exponential-sum

Consider the absolute value of the following exponential sum:

$\left|\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}(ux+vy-wxy)}\right|$

for given $u,v,w\in\mathbb{F}_p$ with $w \neq 0$.

Through computer experimentation I have observed that this is always equal to $p$, but I am unable to prove this for the case where both $u \neq 0$ and $v \neq 0$.

Why is this true? And if it is not, is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $(1+ax)(b+vy)$ and identify with $b+ux+vy-wxy$, assuming that $u\ne 0,v\ne 0$.

So $a\ne 0,v\ne 0$ and it is immediate that $$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}(1+ax)(b+vy)} =p$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I believe I am following your reasoning up to the part where you conclude that the final sum is $p$. Is this a standard result (do you have a reference in this case) or otherwise easy to see? I fail to see it. I only know of the theorem that says that $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}f(x)} = 0$ if $f$ is linear.

Comment: I guess we can split it as $p + \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p \wedge x \neq -a^{-1}}\sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}(1+ax)(b+vy)}$, where $(1+ax)(b+vy)$ is linear in $y$ because $v \neq 0$ and $1+ax \neq 0$, implying that the sum vanishes.

Comment: @user749472 It may be simpler to think that when $a\neq0$ and $v\neq0$ both $r=1+ax$ and $s=b+vy$ range over $\Bbb{F}_p$ independetly as $x,y$ do. Therefore the sum is really
$$\sum_{r\in\Bbb{F}_p}\sum_{s\in\Bbb{F}_p}e^{2\pi i (rs)/p}.$$ The value of that sum follows immediately from ortohogonality.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. You would split the sum in two parts, right? One where $r = 0$, and another part where we sum over all $r \neq 0$. If $r =0$, then we have a sum of trivial characters, which sums up to $p$ by orthogonality. If $r \neq 0$, then we have a sum of non-trivial characters, which sums up to $0$ by orthogonality. I am trying to learn this material and have only seen these results for single sums (as opposed to double sums), which is why I am trying to be very verbose, to check if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @user749472 That's more or less the way it goes. The inner $s$-sum is zero unless $r=0$ in which case it is $p$, so the sum is $1\cdot p+(p-1)\cdot0=p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen All right. Thank you.